# How do I go about writing new controls in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I'm looking to create controls based on text boxes that validate numeric fields and restrict them to certain ranges without having to write all the callbacks for each control on the form.

Does anyone know of a tutorial on how to create and use such things?

Or alternatively, as I can't be the first person to have this requirement, are there a set of such controls available for use anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the default text box, using the Validate event, or alternatively, if you need "live" checking then you could check in the KeyPressed, Change, etc events.

Comment: thank you for that. It isn't quite what I was looking for, but may prove helpful. I didn't know about the Validate event.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use [control arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232596%28v=VS.60%29.aspx). Google turned up [this tutorial](http://www.visualbasic6class.com/validatearray.html). You could encode the minimum/maximum range into the `Tag` property of each individual control, or you could use the `Index` to look them up from arrays.

You *can* [create a user-defined control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229115%28v=VS.60%29.aspx) in VB6 but I'm not sure it's worthwhile for this task. You have to write a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: thank you; that is what I was looking for, although as you say it might be over-the-top for such a simple job.

Comment: @Brian I was also thinking that Microsoft may drop support for VB6 eventually. It might not be worthwhile to be constructing new VB6 custom controls nowadays. Upgrading a VB6 custom control to VB.Net is (as far as I can remember) harder than upgrading control array code, so you might be storing up trouble for the future.

Comment: although your answer is more strictly the correct answer to the question, I'm going to accept Jens's answer as that is what I am going to do. Thank you for your help, though.